# How do your vassals determine their capitals

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Is there any way to influence where your vassals capitals are?

If you give an unlanded courtier a county, then a higher rank title and any amount of titles below it, they will usually keep the first county as their capital, even if it not in the de jure realm of their primary title. In this way, I've kept capitals of far away kingdoms near my own capital.

Does this strategy work long term?

Answer (score 1):

I believe non-player characters will only choose to move their capital province to the [historical *de jure* capital](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Capital#De_jure_capital) of their primary title. All de jure kingdoms and duchies have a *de jure* capital, along with some titular titles.  Apparently the AI will even go so far as revoking the title of the capital province from a vassal if necessary to do so.

I'm not sure what impact this would have on your strategy because I'm not sure of what benefit exactly you're trying to achieve by controlling where your vassals have their capitals. I think the only way you can limit the movement of a vassal's capital is to either ensure either you or the vassal owns the *de jure* capital province. Otherwise your vassal is likely to go to war eventually to get it.

Comment: Is there any opinion penalty if two dukes have control of the other's de jure counties (to prevent capital switching)? They shouldn't be angry at me as long as the only lands I control in their de jure territory are under a vassal of their rank (thus no Desire Control of title/vassal).

As for why, I prefer to have vassal capital's next to my own (and all other vassal capitals) as it allows for easier crushing of revolts as my personal troops will immediately be able to take their best holding.

Comment: @TahsisClaus They won't have an opinion penalty with you, but they'll still want their *de jure* territories, and will eventually go to war to get them if they can. Note that a vassal king can go to war regardless of crown authority laws if he's not your *de jure* vassal.